# Multimarkdown to custom HTML Template

Tags: html, xslt, markdown, multimarkdown

How do I use [MultiMarkdown 4](https://github.com/fletcher/MultiMarkdown-4) to take my markdown document and create a full custom HTML document.

As just using `multimarkdown file.md > file.html` would create the body of the HTML document I could just copy and paste this result into my HTML template, but if I want further control over it, such as ensuring the correct syntax for my code blocks to use [prism.js](http://prismjs.com) syntax highlighter and other similar things how can this be achieved? The closest I have come is some information on using XSLT, however I can't find any documentation in using this with multimarkdown output.

If someone could point me in the right direction it would be a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple, somewhat hackish way would be to prepare a `header.html` file containing e.g

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>my page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
```

and a `footer.html` containing e.g.

```
  </body>
</html>
```

then, you could do:

```
$ cat header.html > file.html
$ multimarkdown file.md >> file.html
$ cat footer.html >> file.html
```

Alternatively, you could use [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) instead of multimarkdown, which already includes a templating mechanism, or any other templating solution like [mustache](https://mustache.github.io/) or even XSLT if you like that syntax.